# error on access code below. keeps looping

Tags: vba, ms-access

The below code keeps looping, and I don't know how to exit the loop.

```
Private Sub Extension_AfterUpdate()
   
Dim AnswerYes As String
Dim AnswerNo As String

If [Extension] = "Yes" Then
    
    AnswerYes = MsgBox("Do you wish to create a new case for this customer?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Response")
                
    If AnswerYes = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "ManagersLogF", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acForm, "ManagersLogF", acNewRec
    Else
        [Extension] = "No"
    End If

Else
End If
End Sub
```

With the above the msgbox doesn't keep prompting but with the one below yes.

```
Private Sub Extension_AfterUpdate()
   
Dim AnswerYes As String
Dim AnswerNo As String

If [Extension] = "Yes" Then
    
    AnswerYes = MsgBox("Do you wish to create a new case for this customer?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Response")
                
    If AnswerYes = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
        DoCmd.OpenForm "ManagersLogF", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acForm, "ManagersLogF", acNewRec
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPaste
    Else
        [Extension] = "No"
    End If

Else
End If
End Sub
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no loop in the code you posted, so it cannot *keep looping*. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: i forgot to include that this is a Private Sub repeat_AfterUpdate(). maybe that's why it is in a loop. but i dont know how to exit the loop after the first instance. when it copies the record in an new record form, all the fields are prepopulated because of the copy/paste. but then i get the question of the msgbox again.

Comment: You need to post the complete code that will reproduce the issue in your post. Without the code, no one can help. If the problem is that your code keeps looping, then we need to see the code that contains a loop. Please read the post I linked in my previous comment. You can also see the [help/on-topic] guidelines, which require that you provide that [mre] when asking debugging questions about code.

Comment: that was the completed code. i just add a pic of the code on the question. the form has a field called repeat. it is a drop down with default value set to "NO", then when it is changed to "YES" it triggers the afterupdate event in the pic above.

Comment: No, it isn't. That's several lines out of context that **do not contain a loop that can keep looping**. The code you've posted **cannot keep looping**, no matter how many times you claim it can. And images of code are useless; see [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for a list of the many reasons why. Once again, read [mre] and provide the actual code. Without it, you're not going to get help here.

Comment: i read both of the link. i added a new field to my table called extension. with a dropdown of yes/no. then i try to replicated the same issue. i added the field to the access form i have for the table and went to the field properties and created after update event with the code i sent. i will paste the new code there. the funny thing is that i only use the commands to open the form and got to add a new record and i dont get the msgbox twice. but when i do it with the other yes. that is weird.

Comment: Well, I assume because you are handling the `AfterUpdate()` of the control, and within the method you are setting it again, i.e. calling the method again. Use a module level boolean flag to manage the flow when setting it in code `[Extension] = "No"`.

Comment: sorry, but i am new to access and that code i was able to do it by converting what i did in the front end to VBA code, an option provided by access. if you could help me on how to do it, i will really appreciated.

Comment: after a lot of research, i found why it keeps the popping up the msgbox. the issue is that after duplicating the record the new that was duplicated, it will have the Extension field as "yes" because it is duplicating the previous record, which triggers the duplication when you put yes. i will need to populate only certain fields, and leaving the Extension field empty. that will stop the msgbox from popping up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't save the record, so it will not read the "No". So:

```vb
Private Sub Extension_AfterUpdate()
   
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    If Me![Extension].Value = "Yes" Then
   
        Answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to create a new case for this customer?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Response")
                
        If Answer = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "ManagersLogF", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
            DoCmd.GoToRecord acForm, "ManagersLogF", acNewRec
        Else
            Me![Extension]Value = "No"
            ' Save record.
            Me.Dirty = False
        End If
    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you Gustav but the one that keeps looping in the second code. with the first one it does not loop. in the second code when i tried to copy the current record and paste it into a new one after answering the question, then i get the questions of the msgbox again and again until i click "no".

Comment: Then modify it as I showed for the first.